# Azure Container Instances - Connection to ACR that does not public access

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

We need to have ACR exposed only to selected networks (not All networks). How should container instance be configured in order to be able to pull images from ACR? We deploy ACI using ARM template.

Full context:

We are building image in Azure DevOps (using microsoft-hosted agent, calling `az acr build .. --agent-pool <agentpool-name>`. The build is successful, however when we want to create the container instance (using Azure Powershell and ARM template) we get an error that the image is not accessible in the container group.

However, when I make ACR accessible by all networks, everything works, so I guess there must be some ACR setting that would allow to pull image from ACR to ACI using microsoft-agent.

Answer (score 0):

You can make deploy to Azure Container Instances from Azure Container Registry using a [managed identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/using-azure-container-registry-mi) or [service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-using-azure-container-registry)

Only an Azure Kubernetes Service cluster or Azure virtual machine can be used as a host to access a container registry using a service endpoint. Other Azure services including Azure Container Instances aren't supported.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-vnet#preview-limitations

Other Azure Container Instances limitations:

- Currently, only Linux containers are supported in a container group deployed to a virtual network.
- To deploy container groups to a subnet, the subnet can't contain other resource types. Remove all existing resources from an existing subnet prior to deploying container groups to it, or create a new subnet.
- You can't use a managed identity in a container group deployed to a virtual network.
- You can't enable a liveness probe or readiness probe in a container group deployed to a virtual network.
- Due to the additional networking resources involved, deployments to a virtual network are typically slower than deploying a standard container instance.
- Outbound connection to port 25 is not supported at this time.
- If you are connecting your container group to an Azure Storage Account, you must add a service endpoint to that resource.
- IPv6 addresses are not supported at this time.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-virtual-network-concepts#other-limitations

Comment: Sorry, added full context to the OP. Could you check it, please?

Comment: Here is an answer from Microsoft Q&A:
Instances of certain Azure services including Azure DevOps Services and Azure Container Instances are also unable to access a network-restricted container registry
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/193123/azure-aci-with-private-acr-and-selected-public-net.html

Comment: "You can't use a managed identity in a container group deployed to a virtual network."
Thankfully this is no longer true; you can.